# What is the typical deliverable to an iOS Enterprise customer?

Tags: iphone, deployment, ios

We are developing an app for a customer that currently has an iOS Enterprise license. My understanding for how we deliver an app to them would be to have them add us as a team to their portal and we would compile with their app ID and their provisioning profile. The deliverable in that scenario would be an ipa file.

Is this how it is typically done? We do not want to release our code to them for obvious reasons (very proprietary). They have asked for a CUL file which I am not familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, even if you are added as an admin to a portal you cannot create distribution (ad-hoc) certificates unless you are logged in as the person who created the account.

They either need to trust you with a private key and deployment profile that they generate, or give you the login to their portal (and the private key).

You should do some research to be sure this is true of an enterprise account which may allow additional delegation rights - have them add you to the team, make you an admin, and see if you can reach the distribution certificate area. You would still at least need the private key used to create the companies development certificate.

You are correct that the final deliverable (that they can deploy) is an IPA file, also if you want to do web deployment there's a plist manifest file that employees can use to load the application directly on the phone without going through iTunes.

I also am unfamiliar with a CUL file.